# How to access one private instance variable in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios6, categories, private

I have a question want to consult you。The following：

class A is from the ios framework， one instance variable B of the Class A is not public, can i through the getter methods defined in the category C  to access instance variable B ？the category  C is  custom for the class A 。

example， the instance variable _viewDelegate  of the class UIView.can I create a category C of the UIView  to access instance variable _viewDelegate?   if define method -(UIViewController*)viewDelegate in the category C;

ThankYou，First !

Comment: Um, what? What are you asking?

Comment: sorry ，My English is not very good！But you should be able to read it！

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing private variables from an external class - iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209843/accessing-private-variables-from-an-external-class-ios)

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "can I access private variables via Category" then the answer is - depends.

First of all, the variable must be defined in the .h file.

If it is, then if marked as readonly, you can only read it. For example:
@property(nonatomic,readonly) somePropertyOfClassA

Otherwise, you can read/write to the property directly without a getter/setter, for example @property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag

The UIView _viewDelegate is marked as @package which means that the member is accessible only from the framework in which it is defined, which is the ios framework.