# access private variable without creating a property

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say, I have defined a private variable `isStarted` in `MyService` class & this class is a singleton:

```
@implementation MyService {
    BOOL isStarted;
}
...
@end
```

**My question:**

**Without** creating property & accessors, **is there a way to access this private variable** from another class after I get a instance of this class `[MyService sharedInstance]`.  If there is a way, could you please show me how? Thanks in advance.

(Please don't talk about "it is not recommended to do so" etc. I understand that. I am just curious about the possibility of accessing private field in objective-c in general. )

Comment: Do you mean without *generating* an accessor using @property, or do you mean without any accessor method at all?

Comment: See: http://jerrymarino.com/2014/01/31/objective-c-private-instance-variable-access.html

Comment: @danh, it would be nice to show how to access private variable without using property only & how to access without using both property and accessors. I am curious about both scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi again=) There is a way - you can get your all class variables on the runtime and there search needed one. Still that is hard way and not recommended. Why do you not want to use properties?

```
  - (void*)getValueWithName:(const char*)varName forClass:(NSString*)className {
        unsigned int varCount;

        Class theClass = NSClassFromString(className);
        Ivar *vars = class_copyIvarList(theClass, &varCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < varCount; i++) {
            Ivar var = vars[i];

            const char* name = ivar_getName(var);
            if (strcmp(name, varName) == 0) {
                ptrdiff_t offset = ivar_getOffset(var);
                unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char *)(__bridge void*)self;
                free(vars);
                return (bytes+offset);
            }

        }



 free(vars);
        return NULL;
    }
```

And casting value:

```
NSInteger t = *(NSInteger*)[self getValueWithName:"p" forClass:@"ViewController"];
BOOL checkBool = *(BOOL*)[self getValueWithName:"boolean" forClass:@"ViewController"];
NSString *checkString = *((__unsafe_unretained NSString **)([self getValueWithName:"string" forClass:@"ViewController"]));
```

Comment: Your question to me is really not making any difference as "do use property". As my question says , I am just curious about a way to make this possible without creating property. That's it. there is no reason why I don't want to use property. Hope you understand it is just my curiosity.

Comment: Hope this answer helps you)

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer I am expecting. I need to study this code now

Comment: donєt forget to add #import <objc/runtime.h>

Comment: Can you make your code as a function which returns the value of the private variable regardless the type of the variable?

Comment: Sure, wait a minute pls.

Comment: Hope this helps you =) It was tested on test project and all works fine. In the end you need to cast returned object to needed type. I will even improve it more wait a minute

Comment: Does it matter when this variable is an object and when it is non-object type with this function? Both work fine?

Comment: Yes it meters when you will cast result, you will need to cast it to Objective-C pointer using __bridge keyword, as I was doing in function casting it to C pointer, you just need cast C pointer to Objective-C.

Comment: Could you please add one more line of code after your NSString type example to show a non-object type casting with this function's return. e.g. BOOL  thanks.

Comment: Sure, give me one more minute, I will update my Example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115560/discussion-between-volodymyr-and-leem-fin).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if being a singleton makes this different, but here is a similar question.

According to this post, you can.

[Accessing private variables from an external class - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209843/accessing-private-variables-from-an-external-class-ios)

It's kind of old, but I'd give it a shot.

Specifically, this line

```
[object valueForKey:@"variable_name"];
```

Comment: No, singleton doesn't make anything different. I just want to quickly show you I can get a instance of this class. So, you can forget about singleton.

Comment: But to use `valueForKey`, I need to create a property for the private variable, which is not I am asking about. I mean I would end up with run-time error `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key`

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure. The post didn't say you had to make it a property first. Maybe you can't do it without an accessor or making it a property. Private variables are designed to be private, so I imagine that there isn't a convenient way to do access them.